# How to test the performance of an Android phonegap-app

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, mgwt

i made a little nice app with [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) and [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/).

Now i want to do the same app with jquery mobile and to compare the mgwt app with the jquery mobile app.

I want to compare the size and the performance of the both apps.

For example the speed of the change from one view (or side) to the next view (side).
Is this possible to test the speed with a stopwatch for example?

How could i do this testings?

Does i need an android phone or is it better to test it in a desktop browser?
How to test the performance and which tools are needed?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

One option you can use is [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html). Here in this [blog post](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2011/10/phonegap-loading-performance-in-ios.html) you can see  a method to measure the time of events in a phonegap application.

I hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

In case of jQuery Mobile and only jQuery Mobile you can use this js script: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/tools/page-change-time.js

At the bottom of my other article: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600 you will find how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Browsers DeveloperTools (Firebug, Chrome DevTools, Safari Web Inspector) to measure the performance of the different apps.

With Safaris Web Inspector it is possible to measure the performance of an Phonegap app running on a real device. [see Safari Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006515) It can connect to the browser on the iOS device and also to WebViews used by an app, e.g. when it uses PhoneGap.

For Android you can use [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) to get the Web Developement Tools for an app that is running on a device.

The Web Developer Tools offer a lot of possibilities to look at your Application e.g. inspect your DOM Elements, Resources, Network Traffic, Console and also to profile your app. You can call `console.profile()` to start profiling and end it with `console.profileEnd()`. So this would e.g. be an easy way to measure how long a function is executed.